# Django: Input fields in submitted form not showing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

So I am starting to switch form models to class base views. In `EpisodeInfoView`, when I comment or uncomment `production = Production.objects.create(podcast=podcast)` under `if podcast` in my `get` method in `pod_funnel.py`, it will show the form and let me fill out the fields but when I check in `Productions` under admin, it shows that is creating the production with the Podcast name (that is being extracted from its `ForeignKey`) [but without the rest of the info (episode number, episode guest, episode title, etc...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFlTl.jpg) And if I remove and add it to create object in post, it show me the form but it does nothing nor does it shows any errors.

**`pod_funnel.py` view:**

```
class EpisodeInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    form_class = EpisodeInfoForm
    template_name = 'pod_funnel/forms_episode_info.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        initial_values = {}
        user = request.user

        # Lets get client and podcast for the user already. if not existent raise 404
        client, podcast = get_podfunnel_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)
        if client is None or podcast is None:
            raise Http404

        if podcast:
            initial_values['podcast_name'] = podcast.name
            initial_values['podcast_id'] = podcast.id
            production = Production.objects.filter(podcast=podcast).first()
            # production = Production.objects.create(podcast=podcast)

            if production:
                initial_values['episode_number'] = production.episode_number
                initial_values['episode_title'] = production.episode_title
                initial_values['episode_guest_first_name'] = production.episode_guest_first_name
                initial_values['episode_guest_last_name'] = production.episode_guest_last_name
                initial_values['episode_guest_twitter_name'] = production.episode_guest_twitter_name
                initial_values['episode_summary'] = production.episode_summary

        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # lets get the data
            # podcast_id = form.cleaned_data.get('podcast_id')
            production_id = form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
            episode_number = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_number')
            episode_title = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_title')
            episode_guest_first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_guest_first_name')
            episode_guest_last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_guest_last_name')
            episode_guest_twitter_name = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_guest_twitter_name')
            episode_summary = form.cleaned_data.get('episode_summary')


            user = request.user

            # Get the production
            # podcast = get_object_or_404(Podcast, id=podcast_id)
            production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)

            # Lets see if we have client and podcast for the user already
            client, podcast = get_podfunnel_client_and_podcast_for_user(user)

            if production is None:
                production = Production.objects.create(podcast=podcast)
            production.episode_number = episode_number
            production.episode_title = episode_title
            production.episode_guest_first_name = episode_guest_first_name
            production.episode_guest_last_name = episode_guest_last_name
            production.episode_guest_twitter_name = episode_guest_twitter_name
            production.episode_summary = episode_summary
            production.save()

            # TODO: Needs to redirect to next step
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('podfunnel:episodeimagefiles'))

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**`episode_info.py` form:**

```
class EpisodeInfoForm(forms.Form):

    podcast_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False, max_length=100, disabled=True)
    podcast_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget)

    production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)

    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget)

    episode_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput, required=True)
    episode_title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    episode_guest_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    episode_guest_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    episode_guest_twitter_name = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    episode_summary = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: Can you include your html template?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using CreateView/UpdateView and initial data dictionary for setting values then moving your save functions to the form itself. This way the view is much smaller, and the logic is in the form.

This would be similar for the admin:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1727/